# Custom attribute change content using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There is some problem with my js script 
Its executing perfectly but at browser is in running stage like in infinite look. Browser is not stopping.

IS there any issue with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p MyTag="home_id">home</p>
        <p>33333333333</p>
        <p MyTag="content_id">Content</p>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var a = 'New text';
            $('[MyTag]').each(function(index) {
             document.write(index + ': ' + a + "<br>");
            });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using data attributes instead of creating totally new attributes on a global level. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change value in every tag you can use below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var a = 'New text';
   $('[MyTag]').each(function(index) {
     $(this).html(index+':'+a);
     $(this).val(index+':'+a);
   });
});
```

html(): In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get/set the contents of any element.
val() : Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var a = 'New text';
       $('[MyTag]').each(function(index) {
         $(this).html(index+':'+a);
       });
    });
```

good luck

Comment: yo want set value to each [MyTag] ok??

Comment: thank you for your answer. its helpfull. but i want same code to set value also for every MyTag. It may be input , checkbox, select.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.write, or you have to often handle such problems. If you want to append some content to such elements, use the `append`-method from jQuery

```
$('.element').append($("<span />").text("your text.."));
```